OpenSearch: Querying elements of an array
I suppose this should be obvious but I'm a raw noob wrt OpenSearch and I'm clearly missing something:
I have a collection of documents that contain arrays of keywords of the form:
{
  "keywords": [ "foo", "bar", "baz", "woof", "etc" ]
}

and I would like to search the documents for matching keywords, for example foo AND bar, such that a document containing foo and bar is selected but a document containing only foo or bar is not.
I've tried
"query": {
    "bool": {
        "must": {
            "match": {
                "keywords": "bar"
            },
            "match": {
                "keywords": "foo"
            }
        }
    }
}

and multiple variations on that theme but that doesn't appear to work.
Any guidance from wiser heads would be greatly appreciated.

Answering my own question, it appears that the "anded" portions of the query must be in an array, as, for example,
"query": {
    "bool": {
        "must": [
            {
                "match": {
                    "keywords": "foo",
                },
            },
            {
                "match": {
                    "keywords": "bar",
                },
            },
        ],
    },
},

I honestly have no idea where this is documented but I happened to figure it out by inference in this forum posting.
I hope this (a) helps someone else and (b) gives the wiser heads a good laugh at my ignorance. . .
